# Count occurences of a specific node in XML file

Tags: javascript, xml

I want to read this XML file in JavaScript function and count the Department nodes, can anybody help me out?

XML file:

```
<Departments>
<Department>
<name>name1</name>
<code>code1</code>
</Department>
<Department>
<name>name2</name>
<code>code2</code>
</Department>
<Department>
<name>name3</name>
<code>code3</code>
</Department>
</Departments>
```

Comment: How are you getting hold of this XML? Have you got it via Ajax? Is it stored in a string?

Answer (score 1):

How about

`xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("Department").length;`

If you need some quick code to get the xml:

```
var xmlHttp =(window.XMLHttpRequest)? new XMLHttpRequest(): new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');

var url = "departments.xml";
xmlHttp.open('GET', url, false); // syncronous
xmlHttp.send();
var xmlDoc = xmlHttp.responseXML;
```

Answer (score 0):

using E4X in Javascript,  `Departments.Department.length();`

Answer (score -1):

Just count how many times `"<Department>"` occurs in the string.